# Move Image to Right of Card in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-float

Basically, I am having trouble figuring out how to move an image to the right of a card using bootstrap, similar to the function of card-img-top or bottom.

Using the [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/), this is what I've done.

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">...</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">....</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                            <img class="float-right" src="Images/template.png" alt="sans" width=200px/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Float-right doesn't help, as we want the image to be completely on the right side of the card.

This is what it looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5BgV.png)

And this is what it **should** look like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijgec.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the picture where is should look like you have two columns of content.

text and image.

So let's try:

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="row card-body">
                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <h5 class="card-title">...</h5>
                           <p class="card-text">....</p>
                           <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                        <img class="col-sm-6" src="Images/template.png" alt="sans"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly :D. Could not be more grateful

Comment: @JackTapia if this is the correct answer you need to click on the checkmark next to the up/down arrows to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the grid row&cols inside the `card-body`...

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some text ehre</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                            <img class="" src="//placehold.it/200" alt="sans" width="200px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

***Or,*** use flexbox (`d-flex`) with 2 containers...

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/0FzyCXffUd

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it with Bootstrap 5. I wanted the image on the right for large screens but on top for anything smaller.

The secret sauce seem to be row + flex-row-reverse + card-img-end, for an image on the **right**.

```
 <div class="container my-5">
    <div class="card row flex-row-reverse">
        <img class="col-lg-4 card-img-end img-fluid p-0" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
        <div class="col-lg-8 card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title">Blog entry</h1>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want the image on the **left** the sauce is row + flex-row + card-img-start.

```
<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="card row flex-row">
        <img class="col-lg-4 card-img-start img-fluid p-0" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
        <div class="col-lg-8 card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title">Blog entry</h1>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find display flex useful. You will need to fiddle with the column sizing to cater for your image size.

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.card-body>div {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>

          <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div>

          <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="sans" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```